# WPF return value from checkbox unchecked event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

How can I return a value from when check-box is unchecked? I noticed that you need to create a converter but is there an easer way of doing that?

XAML

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" Visibility="Hidden"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="149,135,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" TextChanged="textBox4_TextChanged"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Party?(4 or more)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" Width="116" Height="23"/>

    </Grid>
```

C#

```
private void checkBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handle(sender as CheckBox);
        }
        private void checkBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Handle(sender as CheckBox);
        }

        void Handle(CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            bool chkd = checkBox.IsChecked.Value;

            if (chkd)
            {
                textBox4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                textBox6.IsEnabled = IsEnabled.Equals(false);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox4.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney updated

Comment: Still unclear what you're trying to do. Also, you don't seem to have set the `Unchecked` event for your `CheckBox` (so `checkBox_Unchecked` would never be hit).

Comment: aside from Binding theVisibility of the textboxes  to your checkbox, your solution is as easy as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

Add a handler for the Unchecked event in your XAML, and your code will get called.

Snippet:

```
Unchecked="checkBox_Unchecked"
```

Complete:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Party?(4 or more)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="checkBox_Checked" Unchecked="checkBox_Unchecked" Width="116" Height="23"/>
```

When working with controls/events and to help discover what is available, see the Properties window and Events as in the below image:

[image]